# Select a check box in Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

[image: Table element which will have check boxes to check]

I need to select a check box as shown in below image. I tried giving "Set Checked" on Navigate stage but it didn't seem to work.

When i try to capture the Checkbox element using HTML Mode, it is getting captured as a HTML Element and not HTML Checkbox.

Can anyone help me here please.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects, a lot of times it was possible to use action "Write", and write value "True" to this element.

If not, then it should be possible to change the element type directly in the Application Modeler. Please inspect first your element, and then change these two parameters:

- Element type = "HTML Check Box"
- Data Type = "Flag"

Afterwards, in "Navigation" stage, there should be an action "Set checked" available.

For reference, I was able to inspect the logo from w3schools.com and mark it as checkbox in BluePrism. [image: Printscreen]

Comment: Any other ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

Just take your datatype as 'Text' and set it to click centre in navigation.

While running the step it will set it checked and proceed it further.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the "Set Checked" action as part of a Navigate stage, you have to set the "Checked" parameter in the lower portion of the Stage Properties window to "True".

[image: Blue Prism image]

Answer (score 0):

Identify the required check box in Active Accessibility SPY Mode. The element Type for this will be Check Box(AA), Change it to Active Accessibility from the drop down. And then use this element in Navigate stage and select "Global Mouse Click Center" in the Actions drop down, to Check this check box